# Check if DateTime in DB is more than 90 days old via Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime

UPDATE

Evidently I didn't include enough data, sorry!

What I need to do is set 'campaign_Status' = 6 when 'campaign_Date' is more than 90 days old.

---

Hi,

I have a column (campaign_Date) which stores a DATETIME. Using a Stored Procedure I need to check if the stored date is 90 days old (or more).

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to return all rows from the table where Campaign_Date is more than 90 days old?

Answer (score 12):

This will return all old campaigns:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   campaign_Date <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

This will select `1` if campaign is old, `0` otherwise:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN campaign_Date <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    mytable
```

Note that the first query condition is *sargable*: it will allow using an index to filter the dates.

This will update all old campaigns with status `6`:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     campaign_status = 6
WHERE   campaign_Date <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 6):

See the DateAdd function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Campaign_Date <= DateAdd (d, -90, GetDate())
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on the previous answers, wrapped in a stored procedure (as seemed to be asked):

```
CREATE PROC sp_Campaign_Archive AS

    UPDATE [Campaign Table]
    SET Campaign_Status = 6
    WHERE DateDiff(day,Campaign_Date,GetDate()) >= 90

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IIF(DATEDIFF(d, campaign_date, getdate()) >= 90, true, false) 
AS IsNinetyOrMoreDaysOld
FROM myTable
```

EDIT: If you wish to pick records which are 90 or more days old,

```
SELECT campaign_date
FROM myTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, campaign_date, getdate()) >= 90
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select campaign_Date, 
    case when getdate() - campaign_Date >= 90 then 'yes' else 'no' end as Is90DaysOldOrMore
from MyTable
```

**UPDATE:**

You can update the records like this:

```
update MyTable
set campaign_Status = 6
where getdate() - campaign_Date >= 90
```

Because this status will go out of date rapidly because it is date-dependent, you could make it a calculated column instead.